# Template Thymeleaf não carrega laytou:fragment

Tags: spring-boot, template, thymeleaf

Estou tentando inserir um fragmento de formulário via template engine thymeleaf no springboot. Porém, esta carregando o template e outras partes inseridas menos o formulário(elementos bootStrap).

OBS:

- Carrega o template referenciado menos o fragmento
- Carrega outros fragmentos que não sejam o formulário
- ARQUIVO POM.XML - Foi inserida as dependências atuais do thymeleaf
- bootstrap.min.css versão 5.0
- bootstrap.min.js  versão 5.0
- SpringBoot versão 4.10
- Thymeleaf versão 2.4.3

**ARQUIVO POM.XML**

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.3
 

com.algaworks
cobranca
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
cobranca
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>14</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf


nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf
thymeleaf-layout-dialect


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


mysql
mysql-connector-java
runtime


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-tomcat
provided


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-test
test


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-devtools

```
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**ARQUIVO TEMPLATE PADRÃO**

Cobrança

teste

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

ARQUIVO FRAGMENTO

Cadastro de título


    
        
            Título Salvo com Sucesso.
            
        
        
            
                Novo Título
            
            
                
                    Descrição
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Data
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Valor
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Status
                    
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Salvar

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver corrigindo a versão do bootstrap.

como estava usando a mais atual beta, possivelmente o thymeleaf era incompativel com algumas classes.